# Cosmos Db Sql Query produces drastically different results when using order by

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a Cosmos Db instance with > 1 Million JSON Documents stored in it.

I am trying to pull data of a certain time frame as to when the document was created based on the _ts variable which is auto-generated when the document is inserted. It represents the UNIX timestamp of that moment.

I am unable to understand, why both these queries produce drastically different results:

### Query 1:

```
Select * 
from c 
where c._ts > TimeStamp1 
  AND c._ts < TimeStamp2
```

Produces 0 results

### Query 2

```
Select * 
from c 
where c._ts > TimeStamp1 
  AND c._ts < TimeStamp2 
order by c._ts desc
```

Produces the correct number of results.

### What I have tried?

1. I suspected that might be because of the default CosmosDb index on the data. So, I rewrote the index policy to index only that variable. Still the same problem.
2. Since my end purpose is to group by on the returned data from the query, then I tried to use group by with order by alone or in a subquery. Surprisingly, according to the docs, CosmosDb yet doesn't support using group by with order by.

### What I need help on?

1. Why am I observing such a behavior?
2. Is there a way to index the Db in such a way that the rows are returned.
3. Beyond this, is there a way to still use group by and order by together (Please don't link the question to another one because of this point, I have gone through them and their answers are not valid in my case).

Comment: I just tried it on a collection that has thousands of documents and am not seeing what you are seeing. It works perfectly well. Can you create a temporary collection with 20 documents then try again? Don't touch anything with the index. Just have the default settings on the collection and run it.

Comment: I don't have a db with so many documents in it, and I can't see your error in my side when  I execute **Select * from c where c._ts > 1615778261 AND c._ts < 1615778478** I can get the same result count with the one append order by c._ts desc. I think you need to try more times to make sure if it came from accident or some unknow reason. Hope for your response whatever it worked or down, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andy and @Tiny-wa, Thanks for replying.

---

I was able to understand the unintended behavior and it was showing up because of the GetCurrentTimestamp() used to calculate the TimeStamps. The documentation states that

> This system function will not utilize the index. If you need to
> compare values to the current time, obtain the current time before
> query execution and use that constant string value in the WHERE
> clause.

Although, I don't fully understand what this means but I was to solve this by creating a Stored Procedure where the Time Stamp is fetched before the SQLAPI query is formed and executed and I was able to get the rows as expected.

**Stored Procedure Pseudocode for that is like:**

```
function FetchData(){
..
..
..
var Current_TimeStamp = Date.now();
var CDbQuery = 
`Select * 
FROM c
where (c._ts * 10000000) > DateTimeToTicks(DateTimeAdd("day", -1, TicksToDateTime(` + Current_TimeStamp + ` * 10000)))
AND (c._ts * 10000000) < (` + Current_TimeStamp + ` * 10000)`

var  isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
collection.getSelfLink(),
XQuery,
function  (err, feed, options) {
..
..
..
});

}
```